# Facebook Graph API - Why Don't Interests Match?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

So, I'm quite flummoxed by this one. Please help if you can.

Let's say I pull from the Facebook Graph API for the following user: https://graph.facebook.com/zeeshan949/

I get:

```
{
   "id": "657563147",
   "name": "Zeeshan Ahmad",
   "first_name": "Zeeshan",
   "last_name": "Ahmad",
   "link": "http://www.facebook.com/zeeshan949",
   "username": "zeeshan949",
   "gender": "male",
   "locale": "en_US"
}
```

But ... if I'm logged out of Facebook and go to his profile http://www.facebook.com/zeeshan949 I see all his interests. Even if I'm logged out.

Am I missing something basic with the Graph API? What gives? How do I access all the other data?

Answer (score 0):

That's intended behavior, not all user data (even public) available via API without approval of user (or sometimes his friend) by granting permissions to access specific information.

See documentation for [`user`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) object and [`permissions`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) documentation.